# How to create a user-defined function that assigns values to an array in another script?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a user-defined function that can assign values (in this case ones) to an array of zeros which is in another script. Is there any way to do that?

I have tried using the code below, I am not sure what I did wrong because it wouldn't update the values of my array at all. I am new to programming!

```matlab
% Main file
n = zeros(3);
assignval(0, 2, n);

% User-defined function
function assignval(s, e, n)

for i = s:1:e
    n((i+1),1) = 1;
end
```

I expect that the whole first row values to be 1, but instead after running the program it is still zero. Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: You need to define `n` as the output argument of `assignval`

Comment: Why do you need a function for this? `n([s:e]+1, 1) = 1` can easily be done inline. Why are you trying to use zero-based indexing?

Comment: It was for an assignment, and I am instructed to use a user-defined function. Thanks guys!

Comment: It's probably best to mention restrictions like this. Otherwise you'll continue to get questions like, "Why would you want to do it that way? It's much easier this way!"

Comment: Ahh, ok! Will do for next questions. Cheers!

Comment: ... @greengrass62 needs to learn to not reply to homework questions, too. Shades of unethical here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code

```
% Main file
n = zeros(3)
n2 = assignval(0, 2, n)

% User-defined function

function [n] = assignval(s, e, n)

for i = s:1:e
    n((i+1),1) = 1;
end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried it, and it works. Cheers!